# How to use mail( ) in PHP

Tags: php, forms, email

What am I doing wrong? I receive only the "Comment:" without any actual body, or is it the placing of the code?

The first part is PHP that uses mail():

```
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"]).""; 
mail('a.nurk@gmail.com', 'kjjk', $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
```

And the second part is my form:

```
<form action="javascript:parseResponse();contact-us.php" method="post"      name="ajaxcontactform" id="ajaxcontactform">
    <div class="contacttextarea">
        <input name="contactformid" id="contactformid" type="hidden" value="1" />

        <fieldset>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="5" rows="5" class="contacttextarea"onfocus="if (this.value == 'Пожалуйста, оставьте сообщение.') {this.value = '';}">Пожалуйста, оставьте сообщение.</textarea>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="contacttextboxes">
        <fieldset>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="contacttextform" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Ваше имя') {this.value = '';}"value="Ваше имя">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" class="contacttextform" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Номер телефона') {this.value = '';}"value="Номер телефона">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="contacttextform" onfocus="if (this.value == 'e-mail') {this.value = '';}"value="e-mail">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <input name="send" type="submit" class="contactformbutton" value="Send">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` and see what you get.

Comment: Show `parseResponse();` and `contact-us.php` code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php for a fully working mailing script. But your code seems fine. Try using `$_POST['comment']` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the nl2br function and then see if it works. To be honest I can't see anything wrong with that script I can only assume that your $_POST['Comment'] variable is always empty/false.